# Is there upload timeout limit for SharePoint on premises?

Tags: sharepoint-server, list, sharepoint-on-prem, file-upload, attachments

I tried to upload large attachment (>1.5GB) to list item on SharePoint On premises 2019 and after 120 sec there was timeout and traffic stopped.

Is there some limitation and how to change it?

Comment: Which version of SharePoint you are using?

Comment: There is a limit of 250MB in 2013 (can be increased) and 10GB in 2016 and 2019. Are you using good network while uploading the files? Did you network connection break before file upload completion.

Comment: @DikshaPoddar Sharepoint Server 2019

Comment: @GaneshSanap is there a timeout limit? If it takes more than 5 minutes to upload and so on?